# How can i work with Jquery in Python Django project

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I can't user JQuery in Django.

This if from index.html

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="mybtn">Send</button>
```

And this is from layout.html

```
<script src="{% static 'js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.6.0.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
```

And this is JQuery Function from index.html

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#mybtn").click(function(event){

            alert("Clicked");
        })

    })
      
</script>
```

This is INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'bonusapp.apps.BonusappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

I checked the file directories Bootstrap in the same directory is working JQuery is not working somehow. Can you help? I've tried many different ways but none of them work.

Comment: check your source, is the browser finding your js files? use your browser's developer tools and look at the console - post any errors here. Without some more information, it is tough to know what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not have the `<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.6.0.js' %}"></script>` within your `<head></head>` head tag then place it within your head tag. If that doesn't work then try having this instead...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```